# How to resize MaterialUI SVG icon?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

[![
Hi all, im trying to make this materialUI icon bigger but im having trouble

I cant seem to change the size, ive tried viewbox but no luck, even tried inline styling.

I need the icon to be bigger than it currently is at the moment.

I

```js
const function App() {
  
  
 
  return (
    <>
    <div className="grid" >
    <div className="panel">
    <img style={{width:"200px", height:"200px", padding:"0"}} src={NI} alt="logo"></img>
    <div className="user">
   <div>
   <AccountBoxIcon
      viewBox="0 0 20 20"
      
     />

    </div>
   </div>



    </div>
    
    <div className="brand-dir">
    <header className="header">
      Brand Directory
    </header>
    <div className="App">
    <BrandTable />
    </div>

    </div>
   
    
    </div>
    
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HT9kY.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HT9kY.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set the size of the icon with the css `font-size` property